# How can I fix this specific NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error?

Tags: angular

I've read about NG0100: [ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100) in Angular, but I can't avoid it in [my case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k63acc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Basically, on the interceptor, I've a service that load a "status" true/false:

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    this.showLoader();

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        return error;
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this.hideLoader();
      })
    );
  }
```

Using `ngAfterViewInit` within app component introduce that error:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.childSelector.loadRecipeRoadmap(data.name);
    });
  }
```

And I need to use it: in fact, when all child are loaded, parent must "send" (once) data to child (only at the beginning). And at some point, I just need to read from child (that's why I use ViewChild and not @Output mechanism).

How can I fix this specific error? Should I sync Observable? Not sure how...

Comment: I would suggest that the show/hide for the loader be handled by a Subject (which is updated by the interceptor), which is then consumed in the component with a `debounceTime` operator on it to prevent race conditions. You can set a value as low as 5ms on the `debounceTime` to limit emissions without visibly affecfting performance

Comment: @Drenai not really. SetTimeout and Promise give the same error. And can't use ngOnInit, because child's are not yet loaded at this time...

Comment: @Drenai seems more a "quick fix" rather than a solution :(

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**It's because you are executing some code in the `ngAfterViewInit`, which modifies the data that is displayed**.

First detection cycle evaluated the `ngIf` to `false`, then `ngAfterViewInit` was executed, then after it the second verifying detection cycle (angular development mode has this additional one) was executed and this time `ngIf` was evaluated to `true`. Hence the infamous error.

There are a few solutions to this:

###### option 1: next macrotask (setTimeout)

Since your data fetching is asynchronous anyway, you can postpone it to be called in next macrotask (after `ngAfterViewInit` is finished) with a help of `setTimeout` with 0 time delay:

```ts
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.childSelector.loadRecipeRoadmap(data.name);
    });
  });
}
```

###### option 2: ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

You may inform angular to run additional detection cycle after you modified the data that is displayed.

```ts
constructor(private http: HttpClient, public loader: LoaderService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.childSelector.loadRecipeRoadmap(data.name);
    });
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

Or maybe more angular-ish way:

###### option 3: fetching data in OnInit + data binding

Instead of waiting for child to be created and interact with it directly, execute data loading in `OnInit` and bind the data to the child component:

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  dataForChild: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public loader: LoaderService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData().subscribe((data) => this.dataForChild = data.name);
  }
```

And bind it with (of course `myData` in child component need to become and input property with `@Input()`)

```html
<app-my-child [myData]="dataForChild"></app-my-child>
```

##### Extra - pending subscription

You are subscribing to the observable, but do not unsubscribe from it (neither with `unsubribe()` nor using `takeUntil()`). Although subscriptions to observables from angular http module doesn't cause memory leaks, it's good to make sure you will unsubscribe from it anyway for a few reasons:

- just because it's a good practice, without wondering whether it's necessary or not. Today it may not be necessary, but tomorrow someone will modify the service and it may not be safe observable anymore;
- If you unsubscibe in `ngOnDestroy`, the pending http request will be canceled, freeing browser pool of used requests
- also no logic in the subscription and in the potential `pipe`'d transformations won't be called, so better performance due to not executing unnecessary code
- and it will allow garbage collector to remove component instance faster

Comment: Excellent. You expose the problem very well, with lots of solution :) Accepted. Can you maybe help me also on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952796/ngaftercontentchecked-triggered-before-element-actually-being-changed-deleted

Comment: Please avoid the `setTimeout` solution, is a bad practice as it runs "outside" the Angular lifecycle, in some cases it can even trigger more detection changes with the risk of creating something very similar to circular calls. Also avoid option 2 unless it is completely necessary to call the manual `detectChanges` (because it starts a new the lifecycle). Option 3 is the best approach as it flows perfectly with Angular Lifecycle

Comment: Also, @carecki, unsubscribed observables does cause memory leaks in Angular. Internally, [the unsubscribe code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/fbcb98dd52795d94001855782d4b018a94a76084/src/internal/Subject.ts#L105) actually just sets the variable to `null` precisely to avoid the memory leak (as it the GC objects are freed from memory when they are null).

Comment: @luiscla27 its funny that some "bad practice" are suggested by the Angular corporation itself, isn't? https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Comment: @luiscla27:
• "outside" angular lifecycle? What? That's how asynchronous code works. And no circular calls, as ngAfterViewInit is called only once per component.
• you linked the code to the Subject class, that's not how every observable handle unsubscription. Observables created by angular httpModule for example cancels ongoing http calls. And typically observables remove references to their subscribers, thus avoiding memory leaks.

Comment: Agree on how asynchronous code works, I said "very similar to circular calls", not circular calls, the lifecycle runs perfectly one phase after the other, the scenario I recall is when you call `detectChanges` is triggered again, by calling `setTimeout` you get "a kind of circular call", as the first call triggers a second lifecycle, and again and again.. it happened to me only once, and was perceived as a performance issue (not an infinite cycle), it is not infinite because the `setTimeout` is not "synchronized" with the cycle, in my case, "the cycle" was triggered randomly from 9 to 21 times

Comment: The scenario I described in the previous comment was headache @markzzz, so is not funny for me :/

Comment: @markzzz, the video shows how to avoid `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error and explains the reasons for it, but also based in the scenario I described, the bad practice would be specifically to use `setTimeout` when you are potentially able to trigger nested calls of `detectChanges` (as one may trigger the other). as "potentially" may be equals to "always" and as avoiding it is not that hard, just do it. There's more scenarios I've encountered to be against the use of `setTimeout` as a "good practice" in Angular, there's not enough space in this comment section to post them.

Comment: Oh, btw... I just realized that I misread `ngAfterViewInit`, you're right about the circular calls @carecki, however I still hope you get my point as it the issue will occur when the developer mistakenly triggered the `setTimeout` by any `ngDoCheck` hook call.

Comment: option 2: ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

In your `ngOnInit()` right after getting your data, add this line: `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`

Answer (score 0):

Build your application structure based on lifecycle principles.

You can refer to [this article](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100) for more details.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33024851)

Answer (score -1):

this might not be the prettiest solutions, but it does fix the error related to the values changing in the service.

```
private _myChild: MyChildComponent;
@ViewChild('childSelector')
set childSelector(val: MyChildComponent) {
  this._myChild = val;
  this.getData().subscribe((data) => {
    this._myChild.loadRecipeRoadmap(data.name);
  });
}
```

you can use property set as well instead on afterInit. its not super clean but it is a way to deal with it especially if its nested with ngIfs or similar.

edit:
here is probably a better aproach than the hacky method above.

Due to the intercepter sets the value in the service its kinda impossible to control the obervable changes on between change detections. However instead of directly binding to the loader in the service you can do something a bit more simple.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoaderService {
  private loaderSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() {}

  show() {
    this.loaderSource.next(true);
  }
  hide() {
    this.loaderSource.next(false);
  }
  getLoader() {
    return this.loaderSource.asObservable();
  }
}
```

have it be an be an observable you return from the service.then set it in afterViewInit

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.loader$ = this.loader.getLoader();
  this.getData().subscribe((data) => {
    this.childSelector.loadRecipeRoadmap(data.name);
  });
}
```

and use that value to check for loading instead. then you avoid it looking at id before change detection.

```
<app-my-child #childSelector></app-my-child>

<div *ngIf="loader$ | async">Loading...</div>
```

stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sfmfrj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Don't really get your solution. Where/when should I use setter? On AfterInit? Mmm, can you give to me a real example?

Comment: I see what you mean. Sorry thats is not what I'm looking for. The data must be loaded and spread from parent, not from child itself...

Comment: @markzzz I updated my answer with a different approach that is a bit more simple but should solve the issue

Comment: i don't want to move the "loader" logic on other component. it must be centralized on its own service, and only there

Comment: its still is in the service, but you dont bind to it before component is ready. then you can avoid this issue.

Comment: The component shouldn't care about other's service functionality. I don't want to insert additional behaviour, rather than the one component is build for, sorry.